# How do I transfer an image from my Imgur account to my Outlook.com account?

Tags: outlook.com, imgur

I want to use it as a signature. I copied the URL and pasted it into my email but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the URL to the .jpg file at imgur to the clipboard.
2. In Outlook.com, click *Cog wheel, More mail settings, Formatting, font and signature*.
3. In the *Personal signature* section, click the *Rich text* drop-down.
4. Select *Edit in HTML*.
5. At the desired location, enter `<img src="http://...">`.
6. Click *Save*.